# KryoSerializer buffer overflow

Tags: apache-spark

I have a few Spark jobs that work fine in Spark 1.2 but not in 1.3 because of KryoSerializer buffer overflow. I tried to increase `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` to 20GB and `spark.kryoserializer.buffer` to 2GB. But that did not help. Am I using KryoSerializer wrong or is it not ready for prime time yet?

Through trials and errors it seems Kryoserializer buffer is capped at 2GB. Not sure if it's by design or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My observation is true: [SPARK-6405](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/49d2ec63eccec8a3a78b15b583c36f84310fc6f0): Limiting the maximum Kryo buffer size to be 2GB. Apparently the technology evangelist at Databrick didn't know about it and told me to increase the buffer size.